# Windows 10 and Debian on separate drives

Tags: linux, windows

I installed Windows 10 on my HDD while I had Debian installed on my SSD. Everything worked alright afterwards, my Debian installation was not affected and Windows is running well.

Unfortunately, however, the Windows boot partion was installed on my SSD, it seems... I was notified of this when I ran

```
# update-grub
```

in Debian, and it mentioned it found Windows Boot Manager at /dev/sda1. Are there any security risks with this (malware-wise)? How can I install both operating systems while making absolutely sure that they are completely isolated?

Answer (score 0):

There are no security risks.  However, if the MBR is modified by one OS, it is possible not to be able to boot the other one, if it is overwritten.

You can keep them completely separate, if thats what you want, if your BIOS supports it.  I dual boot Windows and Linux and each has their own hard drive, containing their own MBR.  I did this by disabling one drive in BIOS and installing the OS.  I then reenabled the drive, and disabled the other and installed the other OS.  I then reenabled the drive.  By default it boots into Windows, as it is drive 0.  I can boot into Linux during POST as my BIOS gives me the option to select which drive to boot from.